# how to view installation information for package to be installed by apt

Tags: debian, ubuntu, aptitude

For ubuntu or debian, for installed package, I can use `dpkg -L package` to view where files were installed by the package. For a package is going to be installed but yet installed, how can I foresee these information?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
apt-file list $P
```

> List the contents of a package matching the pattern pattern. This action is very close to the dpkg -L command except the package does not need to be installed or fetched

http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/man1/apt-file.1.html